# One button with different actions each touch in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, loops

I want to change the text (or the background or the animation or what ever) in each click, what is the best way to do it?

```
@IBOutlet weak var text: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var background: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

@IBAction func play(_ sender: UIButton) {

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5) {

    self.button.frame.origin.y = 30
    self.button.frame.size.height = 200
    self.button.frame.size.width = 130

    self.button.backgroundColor = .yellow

    self.text.textColor = .white

    self.text.frame.origin.y += 110
    self.background.backgroundColor = .black

    self.text.text = "Thanks for grabiN."

    // ..text = "Now click it until it's gone!"
    // ..text = "ComeOn you can do iT"
    // ..text = "Lest time"

    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to change text assigning string values will do. I am not sure what s the question here ?

Comment: add a property `var counter = 0` after click just increase the counter, in the play method you can use `if counter == 0 {}` `if counter == 1` to execute different codes.

Answer (score 0):

create massive and one count param

```
var count = 0
var texts = ["Thanks for grabiN.", "ComeOn you can do iT"]

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5) {

   self.button.frame.origin.y = 30
   self.button.frame.size.height = 200
   self.button.frame.size.width = 130

   self.button.backgroundColor = .yellow

   self.text.textColor = .white

   self.text.frame.origin.y += 110
   self.background.backgroundColor = .black

   let index = self.count % self.texts.count
   self.text.text = self.texts[index]
   self.count+=1
}
```